Is my reasoning about the likelihood of the Venezuelan election vote totals valid?
I am not a stats person, so I could easily make a mistake, but this seems pretty straightforward.
Consider the numbers given by Consejo Nacional Electoral, the Venezuelan election authority, in their Maduro victory announcement, which is the only official information they've given so far:
Nicolas Maduro won with 51.2% of the vote, Edmundo González Urrutia got 44.2%, other candidates got 4.6%
They also provided vote totals for each: 5150092, 4445978, and 462704 respectively.
Take a look at what those numbers equal in percentage terms:
(5150092 * 100) / 10058774 = 51.19999713682801
(4445978 * 100) / 10058774 = 44.1999989263105
(462704 * 100) / 10058774 = 4.600003936861491
That's 51.2%, 44.2%, and 4.6% almost precisely, within four nines of precision. In fact, if you were to add a single vote to Maduro or Urrutia's total, or subtract one vote from other candidates, you would tip them over the tenth of a percent boundary.
I've tried to figured out what the odds are of these candidates all having vote totals at this boundary, and what I've come up with is roughly 1 in 25 million. Extremely unlikely but not literally impossible. Here's my reasoning:
If you simplify the vote total so that around 10 million people voted, which is close enough, then one tenth of a percent is 10k people. so every 10k votes flips over one decimal point.
However, since we're allowing the number to be both one voter above or one voter below the decimal point, that makes it a 2 in 10000 or 1 in 5000 chance that a candidate will have a vote total at this threshold.
If you have a second candidate at the threshold, that's a 1 in 5000 chance given what was already a 1 in 5000 chance, so 1 in 5000 squared or 1 in 25 million.
You can extend this logic to the third candidate (or amalgamation of "other" candidates) but if there's only three divisions of the vote then the first two occurrences imply that the last candidate will also be at the same threshold.
Therefore, 1 in 25 million, right?

You certainly have identified an interesting pattern.  But post hoc probability calculations have limited value and are misleading because they primarily reflect the creativity and intensity of people examining the data, and it's certain that somebody will find something in the data that looks astronomically unlikely. In this case, once one percentage within $10^{-5}$ of an integer is found, you could use this to hypothesize about the next percentage: that would have about a $10^{-5}$ chance of being integral. That chance is far greater than your one in 25 million result.

I agree that motivated analysts are liable find something unlikely about a dataset if they look hard enough and want to declare it to be false data. It's worth noting, however, that the percentages that I describe here don't come from a post hoc search for improbabilities. They were the percentages shared in the same announcement as the vote totals. This analysis just takes the two sets of numbers given and looks at how perfectly they match.
I'm curious about the idea that two integral 1/10 of a percent vote totals might not be independent. Why might that be?

It's not that the data are independent.  It's that there's no way to attach a meaningful probability to noticing that one number is very close to an integer.  Only then can you formulate a hypothesis and test it; and for that test you need a different, independent number.  There's a complication: suppose your hypothesis were that all percentages were within 3e-7 of a whole number.  The second percentage would falsify that hypothesis.  This shows that the conclusions depend very strongly on how you develop and formulate a hypothesis based on the first observation.

@whuber In hypothesis testing a common approach is to take all results further along the tail of the null hypothesis distribution than the result you obtained--ie sum over probs of all results considered even unlikelier under a null hypothesis. So can't we say that an analogue here is to note that a number that results from multiplying total AB.C% (and rounded to nearest integer) is more unlikely than say AB.CD% or AB.CDE%, while AB% would be unlikelier still? And numbers resulting from AB.C% already include those from AB% so no need to count separately if you want prob of getting either form.

@Hypnosifl You can't even get started with hypothesis testing when you have formulated the hypothesis based on the very data you wish to test.

@whuber Estimating probabilities in retrospect is obviously less rigorous but if the goal is just a rough subjective probability I don't think it's completely meaningless. Basically you have to try to imagine all possible outcomes that you think your alternate selves would have seen as giving some meaningful evidence against null hypothesis if they had occurred, the outcomes ranked by unlikeliness, and then you try to calculate the probability under the null hypothesis of all possible outcomes with a rank greater than or equal to one you saw.

@Hypnosifl Fair enough--but with sufficient imagination, one usually arrives at a p-value very close to 1.0!  Your approach is a good way to formulate and screen hypotheses to be tested with independent data.  In the present case, perhaps there are other election results (under the same recent leadership) one might examine?
